# How to add leading zeros to single digit rows in a column?

Tags: r, dataframe, leading-zero

I am using R studio, and I have a data frame of 7 variables. One of the variables is months, and in this column I want to add leading zeros to the single digits (ex= 7 would be 07 but 12 would remain as 12).
How would I do this, where only the single digit numbers in this column get leading zeros but the double digits remain the same?? Please help

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sprintf`

```
df1$months <- sprintf('%02d', df1$months)
```